# _popen work incorrectly with quotation symbol

Tags: c++, command, execute, popen

I have a block of code like this :

```
FILE * file = _popen("\"d:\\a b\\sql.exe\" \"d:\\a b\\la.db\"", "r");
_pclose(file);
```

It can not work and return the result :

```
'd:\a' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

But when I change quotation " to ' at second paramester => It's OK

```
\"d:\\a b\\la.db\"" =>  \'d:\\a b\\la.db\'"
```

```
FILE * file = _popen("\"d:\\a b\\sql.exe\" \'d:\\a b\\la.db\'", "r");
_pclose(file);
```

I want the `_popen` works like a cmd.exe.So,how can I do with this case.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a backslash before the space. I just wrote up this code snippet (I have a file called popen.exe that just prints "test") and it seems to work.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    FILE * pFile;
    char buffer[100];

    pFile = _popen("\"C:\\test\ 1\\popen.exe\"", "r");
    if (pFile == NULL) perror("Error opening file");
    else
    {
        while (!feof(pFile))
        {
            if (fgets(buffer, 100, pFile) == NULL) break;
            fputs(buffer, stdout);
        }
        _pclose(pFile);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes,with just open one file likes your example,it works OK.
But if you use file A to open file B,It will cause error.

Comment: Enclose the entire command in quotation marks

 `pFile = _popen("\"\"C:\\test 1\\popen.exe\" \"C:\\test 1\\popen.txt\"\" ", "r");`